Wedge of curvature and subsequent trace
I am currently reading https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.10322. More specifically, I am interested in understanding the equation
$$i\partial\overline{\partial}\omega = \frac{\alpha'}{4}Tr(R\wedge R-F\wedge F).$$
On the LHS, $\omega = ig_{\alpha\overline\beta}dz^\alpha\wedge d\overline{z}^{\overline\beta}$ is a 2-form (expressed in local holomorphic coordinates), $R$ is the Riemann curvature tensor on a complex manifold $M$, with $\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb C}M=3$, and $F$ is the curvature on $E$ where $E\to M$ is a complex vector bundle.
I have two questions:
1.) How can I understand the term $R\wedge R$? Is this short-hand/professional notation for associating $R$ with its connection $2$-form?
2.) How is the trace taken exactly?
My goal is to write both sides of the above equation in local holomorphic coordinates. The LHS is pretty straightforward. I have trouble massaging the RHS into local holomorphic coordinates.
I understand that the LHS of the above equation is a $(2,2)$-form and we can understand $R$ as a $2$-form with values in $End(T^{1,0}M)$. So I believe that we can understand $R\wedge R$ as a ''matrix of $(2,2)$-forms'' over which the trace is taken so that both sides of the equation make sense (same for $F$). I am unsure of how to make this precise. Moreover, is by $R\wedge R$ meant $(R\wedge R)(X,Y,Z,W)=R(X,Y)R(Z,W)$ (composition of endomorphisms)? Is there a precise definition of the ''exterior product'' for the Riemann curvature tensor? Any help is appreciated.
Edit: Minor correction

The Riemannian curvature is an endomorphism-valued 2-form, i.e., it has type $R \in \Omega^2(End(TM)) = \Gamma(\wedge^2 \otimes End(TM))$. Sections of $\wedge^2 \otimes End(TM)$ have a natural product that is pointwise wedge product on the first term and composition on the second. This is what is denoted $R \wedge R \in \Omega^4(End(TM))$ and then taking trace on the second factor we get a 4-form. It's the same story for $F$ except that we have $E$ instead of $TM$. And of course this trace-after-composition operating on the second factor is just the Killing form of the orthogonal Lie algebra.

Glancing back at this I note that the expression $Tr(R \wedge R - F \wedge F)$ does not make sense: $R \wedge R$ and $F \wedge F$ are sections of different bundles and cannot be subtacted. Presumably the authors intended $Tr(R \wedge R) - Tr(F \wedge F)$ .

@Oliver The individual traces become forms in different bundles. How can the subtraction $Tr(R\wedge R)- Tr(F\wedge F)$ still make sense?
